# Poisson Distribution in Nature

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

The Poisson distribution is utilized for the number of events occurred in a specific interval. There are a lot of events that could be modeled with this distribution such as the number of meteorites or the patients arriving at the hospital at a given time. The formula of Poisson Distribution probability mass function is
$$
f(k;\lambda) = \frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{k!}
$$
where $\lambda$ is called Poisson parameter and $k$ is the number of occurrences. We had this distribution as an approximation of Binomial when $np \leq 10$. However, I would like to know if there is a explanation or Theorem (like Central Limit Theorem For Gaussian Distribution) why some specific events follow this distribution and which relevant characteristics they share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main theorem you can use is the one that links Poisson and Negative Exponential (it is very easy to be proved).

> the interarrival time (time between an arrival and another) in a Poisson process with parameter $\theta$ is Exponentially distributed with mean $\frac{1}{\theta}$

Thus any event represented with a negative exponential (i.e. lifetime of some devices) but viewed as # of arrival can be represented by a Poisson

Comment: In fact, you can prove the count per unit time is Poisson iff the times between consecutive events are Exponential IIDs.